# Extracting a string from JSON without creating literal quotes around the value

Tags: json, shell

I use

```
id=$(cat  an.json | jq '.id')
```

to get an ID from JSON.

When I `echo $id`, the output is `"1a35"`.

How can I cut the quotes `"` to just get the string `1a35`?

Comment: BTW, `cat foo | bar` should in general be replaced with `bar <foo` or its equivalent `<foo bar`; the `cat` format gives `bar` a FIFO on its stdin rather than a real file handle; this FIFO can only be read front-to-back; its length can't be checked; it can't be seek'd around it; its original filename can't be looked up; etc. Also, data isn't available on the FIFO until a separate program -- `/bin/cat` -- reads and then writes that data, meaning you're creating extra overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Tell `jq` to give you the result as a raw string with `-r`:

```
id=$(jq -r '.id' <an.json)
```

We can test that this works reliably in cases where more naive approaches won't; as an example, when extracting an id with a backslash:

```
## suggested approach
$ id=$(jq -r '.id' <<<'{"id": "domain\\user"}'
$ echo "$id"
domain\user

## alternative, corrected to use '[^"]+' rather than '[^"]*'
$ id=$(jq '.id' <<<'{"id": "domain\\user"}' | grep -E '[^"]+' -o)
$ echo "$id"
domain\\user
```